# The morphism $\text{Hom}_A(E,G)\otimes_BF\rightarrow\text{Hom}_A(E,G\otimes_BF)$ is injective when $F$ is free

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A,B$ be two rings. Suppose $E$ is a left $A$-module, $G$ an $(A,B)$-bimodule and $F$ a left $B$-module. Let
$$\nu_F:\text{Hom}_A(E,G)\otimes_BF\rightarrow\text{Hom}_A(E,G\otimes_BF)$$
be the unique $\mathbb{Z}$-linear mapping such that $\nu_F(u\otimes y)(x)=u(x)\otimes y$. I want to show that $\nu_F$ is injective when $F$ is free.

**Attempt:**

Fix a basis $(b_\mu)_{\mu\in M}$ of $F$. Then $u\mapsto\sum_{\mu\in M}u_\mu\otimes b_\mu$ is an isomorphism of $\text{Hom}_A(E,G)^{(M)}$ onto $\text{Hom}_A(E,G)\otimes_BF$. Suppose $\nu_F(X)=0$. Then there exists a unique $u$ such that $\sum_{\mu\in M}u_\mu\otimes b_\mu=X$. Thus $\nu_F(X)=\sum_{\mu\in M}\nu_F(u_\mu\otimes b_\mu)$. By assumption
$$\sum_{\mu\in M}u_\mu(x)\otimes b_\mu=0$$
for all $x\in E$. Assume there exists a $\lambda\in M$ such that $u_\lambda\ne0$. This implies that there exists $x\ne0\in E$ such that $u_\lambda (x)\ne 0$. Obviously
$$0=\sum_{\mu\in M}u_\mu(x)\otimes b_\mu=\sum_{\mu\ne\lambda}u_\mu(x)\otimes b_\mu+u_\lambda(x)\otimes b_\lambda.$$
How can I derive a contradiction from all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basis $(b_\mu)_{\mu\in M}$ of $F$ over $B$. It follows that for all $A$-$B$-bimodules $Z$ we have an isomorphism of $A$-modules $Z\otimes_BF\cong Z^{(M)}$ via $\sum_\mu z_\mu\otimes b_\mu \leftrightarrow (z_\mu)_\mu$.

You already applied this to $Z=\mathrm{Hom}_A(E,G)$, but you can equally apply it to $G$.

So, if $\sum_\mu u_\mu\otimes b_\mu$ lies in the kernel of $v_F$, then for each $e\in E$ we have $\sum_\mu u_\mu(e)\otimes b_\mu=0$ in $G\otimes_BF$. Using the identification with $G^{(M)}$ we see that $u_\mu(e)=0$ for all $\mu$. Since this happens for all $e\in E$, we get $u_\mu=0$ for all $\mu$, and hence $\sum_\mu u_\mu\otimes b_\mu=0$ in $\mathrm{Hom}_A(E,G)\otimes_BF$.

This proves that $v_F$ is injective.